# change prerequisites in makefile at runtime

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am relatively new to make and don't know how to do one specific thing:

The overall process should look something like this:

1. the source files are java sources in a directory like src/org/path/to/packages/*.java
2. I want only to translate a specific java file, but the translation process will automatically translate all dependencies (I say 'translate' because I use j2objc to translate the java files to obj-c files - but that should be of no concern for this question)
   The translated files will be put into the build/ directory with a folder structure reflecting the source folder structure (so build/org/path/to/packages/*.m+*.h)
3. These *.m and *.h files will then be compiled with j2objcc (a clang wrapper) into *.o files -> this step has to be done per file so every file is compiled with a command like `j2objcc -c build/org/path/to/packages/file1.m -o build/org/path/to/package/file1.o`
4. these shall be combined into a static library using `ar`

My problem is that I know which (one) java file I am starting with, but after step 2 I don't know which *.m and *.h files are generated/translated into the build directory. I'd like to read the contents of the build dir after step 2 with a command like `find ./build -name '*.m'` at make runtime but I don't know how to use this as a prerequisite in the make target.

Comment: `make` cannot do this cleanly without you putting the appropriate dependency information in the makefile.  You cannot otherwise get around `make`'s inability to know which `j2objc` run generated any particular `.m` (or `.h`) file.

Comment: Now, if you *assumed*, unsafely, that `build/org/path/to/packages/` is always initially empty, and if you never built multiple of the static libraries in the same top-level `make` run, then you could perform `j2objcc` runs via a sub-`make` wherein you used GNU `make`'s `$(wildcard)` function to identify the `.m` files to compile.  A sub-`make` would be needed because otherwise the `$(wildcard)` would be expanded too soon.  And lest there be any confusion: **This is a brittle, ugly hack.  If you rely on it, it *will* come back to bite you some day.**

Comment: Do  not use make when the files produced by recipes are unpredictable. Java has its own build system and one of the reasons is exactly this. As explained by @JohnBollinger you can always design something using recursive make invocations but don't.